# Search for time in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

This id my table :

```
+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
| id         | playduration | time                | id_his |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
|        129 | 00:00:00     | 2014-01-19 04:08:00 |      1 |
|        190 | NULL         | 2014-01-19 02:20:34 |      6 |
| 1390228962 | NULL         | 2014-01-19 02:09:20 |      4 |
| 1390228963 | NULL         | 2014-01-19 02:06:12 |      3 |
|        188 | NULL         | 2014-01-19 02:00:11 |      5 |
|        151 | NULL         | 2014-01-19 01:06:01 |      7 |
|        195 | NULL         | 2014-01-15 01:10:00 |      2 |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------+
```

and i want to get row `id = 1390228963` when I search for `time = 2014-01-19 02:07:00`
I thought that I have been explained it good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the last row before the time:

```
select t.*
from table t
where time <= '2014-01-19 02:07:00'
order by time desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this mysql query

`SELECT * from tablename where time="2014-01-19 02:00:11";`

Comment: but i don't have no record with that time

Comment: If you have no time column you cannot query for that record.

Comment: Yes i now this but i want to get the record before this time

Comment: @OussamaTn Then just use:
`Select id From tablename where time < '2014-01-19 02:00:11' order by time desc limit 1;`